# Extended asm - Register constraints behaving oddly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, constraints, x86-64, cpu-registers

### Context

Linux 64bit. GCC 4.8.2.

Gas assembly. AT&T syntax.

I just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898729/1791534).

The code:

```
  int operand1, operand2, sum, accumulator;

  operand1 = 10; operand2 = 15;

  __asm__ volatile ("movl %1, %0\n\t"
           "addl %2, %0"
     : "=r" (sum)     /* output operands */
     : "r" (operand1), "r" (operand2) /* input operands */
     : "0");        /* clobbered operands */

  accumulator = sum;

  __asm__ volatile ("addl %1, %0\n\t"
     "addl %2, %0"
     : "=r" (accumulator)
     : "0" (accumulator), "r" (operand1), "r" (operand2)
     : "0");
```

Compiled with **no optimizations** of course.

I made my experiments with `valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./my_bin`

Actually, if I replace

```
"0" (accumulator), "r" (operand1), "r" (operand2)
```

With

```
"0" (accumulator), "m" (operand1), "m" (operand2)
```

I get one less instruction == one cpu cycle saved because there is no registry manipulation

Now, replacing

```
"0" (accumulator), "r" (operand1), "r" (operand2)
```

With

```
"r" (accumulator), "r" (operand1), "r" (operand2)
```

I get 1 cpu cycle shaved as well.

So

```
"r" (accumulator), "m" (operand1), "m" (operand2)
```

Saves 2 cpu cycles.

### Questions

1) Why should we use at least one register if they slow things down ? Is there really a risk of overwrite or something ?

2) Why the heck do "0" instead of "r" slows things down ? it is non logical to me since we just reference the same value (which is accumulator). GCC should not output different code ! "r" could imply choosing another register -> nonsense && slow.

Comment: "Compiled with no optimizations of course." - probably should have. I doubt operand1, operand2 would be stored in memory at all, otherwise. It's simply not correct to consider loading from memory and loading from a register to be '1 cycle'. [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy#Application_of_the_concept)

Comment: I did it that way to be sure to see everything. Yes, so valgrind may lie to me right ?

Comment: Had some time on my hands, so I thought I'd give a clear answer on the apparent results you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into an [asm tutorial](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/), I thought it might be better to look at code generation with and without optimization. I'm using OSX, which is basically the same ABI as x86-64 Linux.

First: you're finding `sum <- op1 + op2`,

followed by: `acc <- sum; acc <- acc + op1 + op2`,
which we can just replace with: `acc <- sum + op1 + op2`; don't need: `acc = sum;`
(this was broken by the way - `op1, op2` are `%2, %3` respectively, and `%1` 'aliases' `%0`)

This still isn't a particularly efficient use of inline assembly, but just to fix things up a bit into something that can be examined:

```
int test_fn (void)
{
    int op1 = 10, op2 = 15, sum, acc;

    __asm__ ("movl %k1, %k0\n\taddl %k2, %k0"
             : "=&r" (sum) : "r" (op1), "r" (op2));

    __asm__ ("addl %k2, %k0\n\taddl %k3, %k0"
             : "=r" (acc) : "0" (sum), "r" (op1), "r" (op2));

    return acc;
}
```

---

Without optimization: `gcc -Wall -c -S src.c` (comments are mine)

```
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp

        movl    $10, -4(%rbp)   # store 10 -> mem (op1)
        movl    $15, -8(%rbp)   # store 15 -> mem (op2)
# asm(1)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %edx  # load op1 -> reg (%1)
        movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx  # load op2 -> reg (%2)
        movl %edx, %eax         # mov %1 to %0
        addl %ecx, %eax         # add %2 to %0
        movl    %eax, -12(%rbp) # store %0 -> mem (sum)
# asm(2)
        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax # load sum -> reg (%1 = %0)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %edx  # load op1 -> reg (%2)
        movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx  # load op2 -> reg (%3)
        addl %edx, %eax         # add %2 to %0
        addl %ecx, %eax         # add %3 to %0
        movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) # store %0 -> mem (acc)

        movl    -16(%rbp), %eax # load acc -> return value.
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

The compiler has made no effort to keep intermediate results in registers. It simply saves them back to temporary memory on the stack, and loads again as needed. It's fairly easy to follow though.

Let's apply your change to asm(2) inputs: `"0" (sum), "m" (op1), "m" (op2)`

```
        ...
# asm(2)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # load sum -> reg (%1 = %0)
        addl -12(%rbp), %eax    # add op1 (mem) to %0
        addl -16(%rbp), %eax    # add op2 (mem) to %0
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)  # store %0 -> mem (acc)
        ...
```

The memory locations are a bit different, but that doesn't matter. The fact that there's a form of `add` with `reg <- reg + mem` means we don't need to load to a register first. So indeed it does save an instruction, but we're still reading from and writing to memory.

---

With optimization: `gcc -Wall -O2 -c -S src.c`

```
        movl    $10, %edx
        movl    $15, %ecx
# asm(1)
        movl %edx, %eax
        addl %ecx, %eax
# asm(2)
        addl %edx, %eax
        addl %ecx, %eax

        ret
```

There's *no* memory access. Everything is done in registers. That's as fast as it gets. No cache access, no main memory, etc. If we apply the change to use `"m"` constraints as we did in the unoptimized case:

```
        movl    $10, -8(%rsp)
        movl    $15, %ecx
        movl    $10, %edx
        movl    $15, -4(%rsp)
# asm(1)
        movl %edx, %eax
        addl %ecx, %eax
# asm(2)
        addl -8(%rsp), %eax
        addl -4(%rsp), %eax

        ret
```

We're back to *forcing* the use of memory. Needlessly storing and loading operands for asm(2). It's not that valgrind was wrong - just the inference that register use was responsible for slowing things down.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations. Makes things clear Brett